# I have a list of nested tuples. [(('employment', 'agency'), 8055), (('track', 'record'), 5472)]. I want to convert it to text file format

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
[(('employment', 'agency'), 8055),  (('track', 'record'), 5472)]
```

I want help to convert this in the format:

employment agency, 8055
track record, 5472

and store this output as a text file.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
lst = [(('employment', 'agency'), 8055), (('track', 'record'), 5472)]
output = '\n'.join(' '.join(x[0]) + ', ' + str(x[1]) for x in lst)
print(output)

# output:
# employment agency, 8055
# track record, 5472
```

I doubt this needs further explanation. Just note that `join` is helpful in this kind of situation.

Comment: Just had to iterate it through a for loop.. Got it! Thanks for the solution!